# How to recieve a json encoded string POSTED and extract them into variables php

Tags: php, json, api

how will I accept a json data

```
{
"ccToken": "75676576765",
"cardType": "CC",   
}
```

which will  be posted in my url and store the values in variables,like

$ccToken="756765676765"
cardType="CC"

I may sound dump..Im just new to this,so I dont know how I will accept a json string posted on  a url..Usually if its variables,I can accept it like,

$ccToken = $_POST['ccToken'];

but for this thing.
and how will be able to sent a response like..200 in  return?

Comment: Your question doesn't include how the data is posted. Is the request body a JSON formatted string or form data? Or, more specifically, `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your entire POST body is a JSON string, you'll need  to pull in and decode the entire JSON from the body:

```
 $raw_post_body = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
 $data_object = json_decode($raw_post_body);
```

Then you can access the json decoded $data_object like:

```
 echo  $data_object->ccToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the javascript JSON.stringify() method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

and the php json_decode() function

https://www.php.net/json_decode

Comment: it might be easier if you posted the code you have so far but in your javascript you could use var json_str = JSON.stringify(obj); to get your javascript object into a json string. You could then post via ajax or whatever then in php (assuming you posted it as variable called data) you could do something like the following: $data = json_decode($_POST['data']); then you could output it with print_r($data) to make sure everything's workind as expected.